# How can I control API usage and allow trial/demo usage?

Tags: php, api, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Chrome Extension that performs some desirable action on certain web pages.

My intention is to be able to sell API keys so that the extension continues to work for customers who have purchased a valid key.

I have already hooked the extension with my site to check if a key exists, otherwise, no data is delivered to the extension.

I use `localStorage` and `chrome.storage` to save the API key obtained from my site. That works fine.

I have also made the extension work for free as a trial/demo when there is no valid key (the extension is just installed, so the user will get 100 queries for free, before a message is popped up to them urging them to buy an API key).

The problem is: if the user deletes the extension and re-installs it again, I will have no means to check if this customer has already used up the 100 free queries.

What can I do to track API usage and at the same time, allow for a free trial usage for new customers?

My back-end API function lives on PHP.

Edit: I don't want to set up username/password since they can get passed from one user to another and then, I end up with one paying customer sharing his account with everyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent user from tampering with a Chrome Extension's free trial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348490/prevent-user-from-tampering-with-a-chrome-extensions-free-trial)

Comment: What stops users to share the key the same way as they may share login/password?

Comment: @AlexBlex users will not get to see the API key. The key is stored in `chrome.storage.sync` where they have no direct interaction with.

Comment: And how exactly it works? It is stored locally as unencrypted sqlite db. Besides, all chrome instances logged into the same account will sync it.

Comment: you must identify the user in a unique way (chrome identity) and track usage server side.

Comment: is it a unique browser-user extension or I can install it in other pcs/browsers after I bought it?

Comment: @sarbuLopex each I would like to count each installation as a separate authorization, independent of the user identity, but if I must link the installation to ghr user account, then that will also be ok

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to track the number of free queries the user has performed. If you do it client-side, as you are storing just in localStorage or chrome.storage that kind of data, its going to be lost if unistalled or cleared. If you do it server-side, the tracking data will live in your database (assuming you're using one for your registered api keys) so you can check if the api key is valid or not.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I can store the free queries tracking information on my server, but how can I make sure that the user doesn't delete the extension and installs it again and get an additional 100 free queries? Is there a way to identify a user even if they delete/re-installed the extension?

Comment: Unfortunately, with client side stuff like chrome extension you are never sure to prevent delete/unistalls or expired uses. You could sort of authentication to recognize the user and bind your license key to their api key. 

in short:
- You implement somekind of easy and fast Auth to use your extension.

Comment: incorrect. sync storage also goes away on reinstall.